# How to trim transparency from multiple images but still keep relative placement in Image Magick

Tags: image, bash, shell, imagemagick

I have three related images - a base image, a glow image and a "dirty" image.  Initially all have the same dimensions and are correctly positioned when I overlay them.

I'm using Image Magick via a shell script to trim the transparent edges off the images.  When I do a simple trim on all the images, it upsets the alignment of the images relative to each other.

I'm looking for a way using bash / ImageMagick to trim / crop the images as much as possible while keeping the relative positions intact.  Or in other words, trim the glow image, and then apply the same cropping to the other two images.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it.  The trick is to get ImageMagick to run the trim operation of the largest image (the glow in my case), but instead of outputting an image, simply output the trim parameters instead.

Then, feed this back into a crops operation on each image, like this:

```
convert Penguin.png  -crop `convert PenguinGlow.png  -trim -format '%wx%h%O' info:` +repage PenguinTrimmed.png

convert PenguinDirt.png  -crop `convert PenguinGlow.png  -trim -format '%wx%h%O' info:` +repage PenguinDirtTrimmed.png

convert PenguinGlow.png  -crop `convert PenguinGlow.png  -trim -format '%wx%h%O' info:` +repage PenguinGlow.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to try with `-crop` operator instead of `-trim`. 
`-crop` simply cut off all images given size and position specified.

Comment: That's probably a partial solution - what I need to do now is figure out where to crop it (I'm processing a lot of these).